# Salting - the order of steps

Tags: security, encryption, hash, salt

When salting a password, which is the correct way (or most effective way)?

A. First hash the password and then hash the hash of the password with the salt like this:

```
$password = "passwd";

$salt = "s0merndslt";

$password = sha1($password);

$salty = sha1($password.$salt);
```

B. Take the password and the salt and hash them together like this:

```
$password = "passwd";

$salt = "s0merndslt";

$salty = sha1($password.$salt);
```

My apologies if this has been asked before but I could not find the answer to this specific part of salting on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reality, either case.

However, your example #1 provides a time tradeoff which will (slightly) slow down brute force password finders.

With the advent of GPUs, simply salting passwords **is not enough**. A GPU-backed brute-force password tool, when given a set of passwords to find, can accomplish short passwords in a matter of minutes (or even seconds).

This is why tools or algorithms such as `bcrypt` or PBKDF#2 exist: they iterate the hashing operation many times to produce a large workload, which makes finding passwords from a hash "infeasible" on commodity hardware.

When in doubt, don't implement your own password hash solution! Use `bcrypt` or PBKDF#2.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a certain library in PHP you'd recommend for working with these algorithms? Something like http://www.openwall.com/phpass/ I did a quick search for bcrypt and PBKDF2 and nothing came up from the official PHP documentation. I'm assuming these aren't natively supported in PHP...

Comment: @Aaron: There are several versions of PBKDF#2 here, here is one linked to from Wikipedia: http://www.itnewb.com/v/Encrypting-Passwords-with-PHP-for-Storage-Using-the-RSA-PBKDF2-Standard Note that you will still need to store the iterations (>5000 at least) and salt as part of the password in your database (or in separate columns, up to you)